# Os ícones do Font Awesome não pega no PrimeNG

Tags: angular, font-awesome

Estou com a lib do Font Awesome instalado e configurado no meu projeto, e estou  com a lib do PrimeNG também instalado, porém o icones do  Font Awesome não está pegando no Datatable do PrimeNG, será que falta alguma coisa no meu arquivo HTML ou será que é o projeto que não está bem configurado.

Essa é minha pagina;

```
  <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
            <p-dataTable [value]="lancamentos">
                <p-column field="pessoa" header="Nome" styleClass="col-data"></p-column>
                <p-column field="descricao" header="Descrição" styleClass="col-data"></p-column>
                <p-column field="dataVencimento" header="Valor" styleClass="col-data"></p-column>
                <p-column styleClass="col-acoes">
                        <ng-template pTemplate="body">
                          <a pButton icon="fa-pencil"></a>
                          <button pButton icon="fa-trash"></button>
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-column>
            </p-dataTable>

            </div>
```

Esse é meu arquivo package.json

`"font-awesome": "4.7.0",`

Esse é meu arquivo angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css",
    "../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/skin-red.min.css",
    "../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/iCheck/flat/red.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

Está aparecendo assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na propriedade icon coloque dessa forma.

```
icon="fa fa-pencil"
```

Isso deve resolver.

Comment: é isso mesmo, muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Disponha.

Comment: Na verdade não é só isso, o fa _AINDA_ está funcionando, mas vai parar de funcionar em breve parece. Com a nova versão do FontAwesome você precisa copiar certinho a tag no [site de doc](https://fontawesome.com/icons/pencil-alt?style=solid), porque o `fa` das imagens _solid_ na tag `class` virou `fas`

Answer (score 0):

Se vc a instalação pelo NPM, acredito que o import correto seja assim:

```
"styles": [
"../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" ],
```

Comment: Não pegou, eu teste, e percebi que a única diferença seria o min, mas não pegou.

Comment: Vai na pasta do node modules e ve se existe esse arquivo, Tbm sempre reinicia o servidor quando vc mudar o angular-cli.json.

Comment: eu já fiz isso também.

Answer (score 0):

Depende da versão do seu PrimeNG, se for 6 já não dá suporte ao FontAwesome, tem que utilizar a biblioteca própria do PrimeNG ex: "pi pi-save"